# Question closed as too localized?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

Why was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429676/user-input-validation-routine-behaves-strange) closed as too localized? The issue was more than a typo. Yes, his issue FAILED at the typo, but there were also many other problems with it that could be potentially useful to other people searching for form validation issues in JavaScript (i.e. not having a `return true` statement).

Comment: +1 for your in-depth answer to the guy, but it's still an extremely localized question. It's great advice, but I don't see how it's going to be useful to future generations.

Comment: That's why I made it in depth, just in case someone did come along searching for potential issues with their validation script. Maybe I am just being a whiny little punk but I thought it was a pretty valid question. Clearly he did some research which is more than we can say for most Stack Overflow users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP asked why his code wasn't working when the second validation was present. The answer was "you have a misspelling." That's it - that's the answer. Anything else is just additional information. Just because you can tack on "oh btw, you shouldn't use the `mysql` functions" and such doesn't make the question any less localized.

The information may be there and quite useful, but it's going to be very difficult for anyone to find it with a question purely based on a typo with virtually no information describing the code.

Your answer looks more like a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), to be honest.

Comment: But a [misspelling didn't fix the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/7znyK/).

Comment: So, there's *another typo* with his regex? Still too localized.

Comment: And then the issue with `document.getElementById('email')` which would have come next. Are we here to help or determine the quality of a question?

Comment: You *have* helped. Him. Good. The problem is it won't help *anyone else*.

Comment: Alright alright. I'll get off it. It probably won't help anyone in the future. There were a lot of things wrong with it but it's not like a user is going to search "Why does referencing `emaill` not work when the element is named `email`"